# Encriptacion/Compresión de recursos(texturas, musica, etc)

Tags: c++, motor-de-juego

Resulta que tengo varios archivos(jpg, ogg, ttf) que uso en un videojuego, actualmente se encuentran "sueltos" junto al ejecutable por lo que pueden modificarse o moverse y el compilado se "rompería" por no encontrar los recursos.

Para evitar esto me gustaría encriptar y de ser posible comprimir los recursos para aligerar el peso del producto final. He estado observando que algunos juegos tienen los recursos "dentro" del ejecutable y seria otra forma de resolver este problema.

Alguna idea de como lograr esto?

Comment: Con comprimirlos debería bastar, si quieres algo raro, usa LZO, al parecer _nadie_ sabe que existe ese método de compresión.

Comment: Para empaquetar recursos, échale un vistazo a [NBT](http://wiki.vg/NBT) (usado por Minecraft entre otros).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si haces eso tu ejecutable pesara demasiado y lo cual no es recomendable cuando se crean juegos.

1.- Te recomendaría manejar un directorio para tus recursos y subdirectorios para tus audios, otro para tus imágenes, etc.
En tu código defines las rutas de acceso a tus archivos.

2.- La otra alternativa es:
Aplicas la primera alternativa, pero creas una pantalla de carga.
Posteriormente conviertes tus archivos a binarios con algún algoritmo que encuentres por ahí o diseñes tu y con una extencion definida por ti mismo.
Al iniciar tu juego que cargue tu pantalla de carga, y aplicas el mismo algoritmo para convertir tus archivos al formato que se encontraban antes 
pero de forma inversa.

3.- La ultima y las mas sencilla es bajarte el código fuente de Unrar y adaptarlo a tu gusto, comprimes tus archivos con Winrar y con contraseña, posteriormente a través de Unrar al cargar el juego que los valla descomprimiendo.

[Código fuente de UnRar pagina oficial de Winrar](https://www.winrar.es/descargas/fuentes)

Creo que las librerías están en C o C++, suerte amigo.

Answer (score 0):

> Para evitar esto me gustaría encriptar y de ser posible comprimir los recursos para aligerar el peso del producto final

Los formatos gráficos (salvo quizás bmp y poco más) y de audio ya usan compresión... no vas a poder comprimir mucho más esa información salvo que los recodifiques y sacrifiques algo de calidad.

Si quieres empaquetarlos lo mejor es usar algun algoritmo tipo ZIP, RAR (cuidado con las licencias) para mantener los archivos agrupados... aunque eso seguirá sin evitar que el usuario mueva los recursos de sitio y el programa no los encuentre.... pero tampoco es un problema tan grave... no hay más que abrir la carpeta de tu juego favorito y mover unos cuantos archivos y carpetas a otro sitio y después *disfrutar* de los resultados.

Por otro lado, embeber los recursos dentro del ejecutable no es buena idea porque eso te va a dificultar la tarea de actualizar el juego... Si la aplicación está dividida en elementos individuales es más sencillo y rápido actualizar únicamente los elementos modificados, mientras que en un paquete monolítico te toca actualizarlo al completo... y hay juegos que pesan varias decenas de gigas...

Lo más recurrente suele ser empaquetar los recursos siguiendo un criterio lógico y, después, cambiar la extensión al archivo resultante. Esto no evita que alguien con unos pocos conocimientos averigue el algoritmo usado para empaquetar y juegue con los archivos... pero si sirve para que la mayoría tenga las manos quietas... que por otro lado si alguien toca los archivos y rompe el producto la responsabilidad es únicamente suya.. que lo reinstale y listo.